# The result of the addition of a char and an int

Tags: java, char, int

Consider the following code:

```
System.out.println('G'+2);
```

The output is 73. Can I know why and how?

Comment: Because the `int` value of character `G` is `71` ?

Comment: What are first 2 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, a `char` occupies 16 bit in `UTF-16` encoding.

`G`'s [unicode](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) is `U+0047`, in binary `0000 0000 0100 1111`.

When you sum a `char` and an `int`(32 bit), the `char` will be converted to `int` by inserting `0` into the begin of its binary representation. So `0000 0000 0100 1111` is converted to `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 1111`(in decimal, 71).

That's why you get `73`.

Comment: It's unicode representation, not ascii.

Comment: `convert` sounds more reasonable.

Comment: @saka1029 That's right. Since 0-128 get the same character in ascii and unicode, I always mix it up. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The fact that ASCII exists is hardly relevant in modern programming environments (except when coding to particular RFCs and perhaps in the tiniest processors.) Basically, if you don't know you are absolutely using ASCII, you almost certainly aren't.

Comment: @TomBlodget I agree with you.

Comment: Good anwser Sir !

Answer (score 0):

It takes ascii value of G and adds 2 to it.

Comment: It's unocode value not ascii.

Answer (score 0):

In  code you are going to add character to int.
Value of character 'G' is  :71

See this for more details: [ascii table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Comment: java uses unicode not ascii.